# Prevent updates to generated primary key column

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have created a table and with an `id` column defined as `serial`. I have inserted two rows, but I can still update the value of the `id` column.

But I need prevent updates to the generated value of the `id` column.

```
create table aas.apa_testtable
(
    id serial primary key,
    name text
)

insert into aas.apa_testtable(name) select ('test')
insert into aas.apa_testtable(name) select ('test2')

-- I want this to be impossible / result in an error:
update aas.apa_testtable set id=3 where id=2
```

Comment: If you don't want to change the `id` value, then why do you run an `update`?

Comment: i need to be column as unique and the identity column is to be static which means after insert then the column could not be change.

Answer (score 1):

You can revoke update on table and grant it on column(s):

```
REVOKE UPDATE ON TABLE aas.apa_testtable FROM some_role;
GRANT UPDATE (name) ON TABLE aas.apa_testtable TO some_role;
```

Remember about role `public`, superusers and other inheritance issues you might have in your setup.

```
--Do not try this, it will not work without revoking table level privileges:
REVOKE UPDATE (id) ON TABLE aas.apa_testtable FROM some_role;
```

Alternative is to create trigger that will check if old != new, but with details provided I don't see need for it.